Scrolling with overflow-x only works once
I'm trying to design a sideways scroll for the row because it has a few inline elements. It works fine, but the problem is that it only works once. I can only scroll once, then it stops working.
I'm not sure what causes this or how to fix it, but I have not been able to find any solution to this problem.
Does anyone know how to solve this to make it work well?
.testujemerow {
 overflow-x: auto !important;
 max-width: 100% !important;
 width: auto !important; }

Full row html

Hi Chad Davis, please provide HTML to replicate the issue. Minimal, Reproducible Example

Working examples will help to understand the problem, please share the proper HTML, and CSS. So we can debug the code. You can also refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

I am so sorry guys, I didn't think it would be necessary. I have added a link to share the specific row in which I am solving the problem.

Working with the example you posted, I can't reproduce the issue you seem to be having. You have created an element with height: 100% that may overflow off the right of the screen. When it does, this introduces a scrollbar just off the bottom of the viewport (because the element is using all of the height). But this scrollbar continues to work no matter how much I scroll with it. You may need more detail on exactly what you are doing and seeing to replicate this issue.
